# Image uploads not working on Chrome

Tags: support, google-chrome, uploader

When I try to upload an image, I'm presented with the following dialog box,

[image: screenshot of dialog box]

The dialog box does not allow uploading either from my computer or by posting a link.

This happens only on Chrome browser (running on Windows). Clearing cache and cookies, and restarting computer do not resolve.

Is this just my computer? Or is this a site-wide bug?

**Additional info:**

Clicking on 'click' to upload does nothing. Dragging an image onto dialog redirects me to the file location on my computer. Clicking 'Add picture' redirects me to `http://[SE-domain].com/upload/image?https=true`.

**UPDATE:**
A Norton extension for Chrome was the source of the problem.

Comment: What exactly happens if you either click where it says click here or drag and drop an image onto that place?

Comment: @RobertLongson Clicking on 'click' to upload does nothing. Dragging image onto dialog redirects me to file location on PC. Pasting a link and clicking 'Add picture' redirects me to 'http://$.com/upload/image?https=true' where $ is the respective Stack Exchange community

Comment: Any errors in your browser's error log?

Comment: No errors on console. I think http://electronics.stackexchange.com/ is at fault. When I try to upload there I get said dialog box, and thereafter all other communities behave the same

Comment: @RobertLongson Are you able to duplicate this behaviour on your computer?

Comment: The uploader, including the electronics site, works for me (Windows, Chrome). I wonder if you got a missing stylesheet or script download or something and now some weirdness is cached on your end, and all the hidden stuff on the uploader is displayed. Just for grins try closing all your site tabs, clearing the cache, then trying again. Does that help?

Comment: @JasonC No. Tried clearing cache, browser history, and restarting computer to no avail

Comment: @ale This dialog appears when I click the upload image icon. Before I even do anything.

Comment: Somebody seriously needs to figure out what the root cause of this is (what the extensions are modifying to cause the issue).

Comment: Related: [Image uploading stuck at Uploading, but none was provided](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357591/55075).

Answer (score 11):

Disabling a Norton extension for Chrome (Norton Security Toolbar 2017.0.0.8) resolved the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Disabling an Avira extension for Chrome did it for me.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro It's a hacky solution and doesn't get at the root of the problem... What attribute of the culprit extensions causes the problem?

Comment: I'm having the same issue with none of these extensions installed.

Answer (score 3):

Disabling *HTTPS Everywhere* extension for Chrome solved the issue for me. After disabling it, I reenabled it with no issue. I was however forced to restart the browser on one occasion.

Comment: I have the extension enabled and no problem with the uploader.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was [Buffer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/buffer/noojglkidnpfjbincgijbaiedldjfbhh?hl=en).

Answer (score 0):

For me, it's caused by [Blur](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blur/epanfjkfahimkgomnigadpkobaefekcd?hl=en).

Answer (score -3):

**Is this just my computer? Or is this a site-wide bug?**
It is both. This image loader breaks on many slower systems [for instance it breaks on the laptop I'm using right now, which is how I got to this question]. If it's a bug would depend on SE's perspective on being useful to all users. For instance, the normal HTML file input method works on all modern systems, SE chooses to use this one. Maybe they don't care? If it's a bug or a feature is subjective.

Comment: Thought police... is that better? ;)

Comment: Not a rant now, but still some noise here, and not really clear what actually cause this to break in your case.