# Image Upload failure: “Request returned an error”

Tags: support, images, uploader

I'm currently unable to use the image uploader. When I press the "Upload image icon", I'm able to select or drag & drop an image from my computer. The image then successfully previews in the uploading interface. However, when clicking the *Add Picture* button, I get the error message:

> Request returned an error [error]

Screenshot:

> [image]

I've had this problem for the last day. Before that, I occasionally had [another image uploading error](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292019/image-uploads-not-working) which was remedied by disabling "antivirus/security" extensions in Chrome. I did so for this new issue also, but then discovered that I had the same problem in Safari where I have no extensions at all.

My cookie settings in both browsers are set to *Allow from current website only*.

Comment: Do the developer tools show a 503 or other error?

Comment: @DavidPostill The error seems to have gone away now, and I can upload images again, even using Chrome which is the browser I use with a few "antivirus/security" extensions. If the problem reoccurs, I will try to check developer tools for more information. (I'm presuming that even though I no longer have issues, doesn't mean that the question is "solved" from a SE community perspective).

Comment: There have been many similar complaints over the last week or so. It appears to be an intermittent error.