# I literally can't upload my profile picture

Tags: bug, profile-picture

In the profile settings page, I clicked "change picture" on the picture tab, clicked "upload picture", and encountered this nonsense when trying to upload. In particular, when I clicked the "drag and drop" area, nothing happened, and no errors appeared in the console. Same issues with the "link from the web" and similar.

(Note: the dark theme has no effect. I tried disabling that also.)

[image: bad image]

For reference, I was going to change it to [this particular image](http://www.isiahmeadows.com/pic.jpg).

Comment: Actually, that looks like some hidden text isn't hidden as it should be. I'd guess this from "Uploading" also being shown, along with "You can also provide a link from the web" while the "Link from the web" textbox is visible. I would guess borked CSS or JavaScript.

Comment: Could it be that the dark theme is making a mess of the page? Or maybe the javascript that drives that dialog got confused.

Comment: I clarified a few missing details. And yes, I tried to add a link from the web, and that didn't work, either.

Comment: And also, it made zero difference with the dark theme disabled.

Comment: Have you tried a hard refresh/clearing your cache? Have you tried multiple browsers? What about disabling any/all extensions/add-ons?

Comment: Whic browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome 60 (beta) on macOS Sierra.

Comment: Using beta browsers and then reporting bugs here is nonsense. Try to repro on a stable Chrome release and/or if you use plugins try disabling all.

Comment: Perhaps it's an issue with the beta version. Stack Exchange is not guaranteed to work on beta versions of browswers.

Comment: @NathanTuggy It likely is, considering I see the exact same layout issues in the screenshot, but I don't have the Norton extension.

Comment: I issued a close vote for the same reason listed.

Comment: There is one answer on the dupe that states another plugin. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/297301/158100 Any chance you use that?

Comment: Nope. None of the ones listed there I used except for HTTPS Everywhere (disabling that had zero effect).

Comment: Strange, if it is indeed something that affects all Chrome users once V60 hits mainstream I do hope the root cause is known and fixed.

Comment: Safari works, though. I just fixed my issue in it.

Comment: No repro with Chrome 60 beta under Windows 10. /cc @rene - the issue is some security software messing with Chrome. I do not use any anti virus, as they are all bad and cause way more trouble than good.

Comment: @ShadowWizard maybe we need for each cause an answer on the dupe, if this OP finds out what is causing their issue.

Comment: @rene very true.